$\oint_{|z|=5}\frac{\cos z}{(z-\pi)^k}dz$

Let $k\in \Bbb Z$, evaluate after discussing convergence of
$$I:= \oint_{|z|=5}\frac{\cos z}{(z-\pi)^k}dz$$


Let
$$f_k(z) = \frac{\cos z}{(z-\pi)^k}$$
if $k\le 0$ we have
$$f_k(z) = \cos z (z-\pi)^{|k|}$$
this function is holomorphic in $D:=\{|z|\le 5\}$ so for the Residue Theorem we have $I=0$.
For $k>0$ we have a $k$-th order pole in $z=\pi$ that lies inside $D$ so as before for the residue theorem we have
$$I = 2\pi i\ \text{Res}_{f_k}(\pi)$$
Now the hard part is to evaluate that residue so I've tried Laurent expansions
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align*}
f_k(z) &= \frac{\cos(z-\pi+\pi)}{(z-\pi)^k} = \frac{\cos(z-\pi)\cos\pi+\cancelto{0}{\sin(z-\pi)\sin\pi}}{(z-\pi)^k} \\
&= -\frac{\cos(z-\pi)}{(z-\pi)^k} = - \frac{1}{(z-\pi)^k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n}\\
& = - \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n-k}
\end{align*}$$
so we need $2n-k = -1 $

if $k$ is odd $k= 2\kappa +1 \implies n = \kappa \implies \text{Res}_{f_k}(\pi) = -\frac{(-1)^\kappa}{(2\kappa)!}$
if $k$ is even I think that the residue is zero

another thing that led me to think that the residue is zero is direct formula for high order poles
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Res}_{f_k}(\pi) &= \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\bigg (\frac{d}{dz}\bigg)^{k-1}\big((z-\pi)^kf_k(z)\big)(\pi)\\
&=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\bigg (\frac{d}{dz}\bigg)^{k-1}\big(\cos(z)\big)(\pi)
\end{align*}$$
Since $k$ is even $k-1$ is odd and looking at cosine's Taylor expansion we know that odd derivatives are zero.

Is this a possible approach? Thank you for the help!

Isn't it a direct result of Cauchy's Integral formula
$f^{(n-1)}{\pi} = \frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=5} {\frac{f(z)}{(z-\pi)^{n}}}dz $ ?

Why is the an absolute value in the exponent. That is just wrong. While it is true when $k\leq0,$ you are defining $f_k$ there and discuss it for all other $k$ later.

@ThomasAndrews The absolute value is there only when $k\le0$, I'm highlighting the fact that denominator jumps up to the numerator and we do not have any holomorphic problem related with $f_k$. Then for $k>0$ is another story. I miswritten something and is unclear what I'm saying?

Right, but you never define $f_k$ anywhere else, so when I saw $Res_{f_k}$ and looked for the definition, I found an apparent one which was wrong. @TurquoiseTilt

@Cheese I did not notice that, for each $k$ basically we are writing derivative of cosine function and I can easily evaluate them, this it's another confirmation of the result I get above I think.
